# How do I toggle one element without the others with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I was wonder how I can toggle one element without toggling others... I just don't want to do this every time:

HTML:

```
<div class="share-toggle as-1"></div>

<div class="audio-share as1">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>

<div class="share-toggle as-2"></div>

<div class="audio-share as2">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.as-1').click(function() {
  $('.as1').slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.as-2').click(function() {
  $('.as2').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Is there a way to write this in short? pls help... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to select all elements, which `className` contains a certain substring:

```
$('*[class*="as-"]')
```

This will select all Elements in the DOM (`*`), of which the `className` (`[class=""]`) has `"as-"` anywhere (`*`) in it.

And then you can use the Element passed as `this` to get the number of the element after the `"as-"` and toggle the wanted element:

```
$('*[class*="as-"]').click(function () {
  let elemNum = this.className.match(/as-(\d+)/)[1];
  $("as"+elemNum).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Better to use `this` or `event.currentTarget` instead of `target`. Any children of that element can be `target`

Comment: Except note that with arrow function there is no explict `this`

Comment: Isn't really working for me. It just removes the as- element without toggling the wanted element...

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but anyway…
Here is, in my opinion, a better solution.

Why is that?
Only 3 lines of code, and not using any regex or partial class names…
See comments in my code for more details:

```js
// You could use class^=[as-] to filter on the classes that start with as-,
// (the ^ would be better than a *, because more specific)
// But I suggest you to use the 'share-toggle' class, there's no need to complicate things here:
$('.share-toggle').on('click', function(){
  // The following will get the .audio-share element that is after the element we just clicked,
  // If your HTML structure is gonna stay well structured like this, it's the finest solution:
  $(this).next('.audio-share').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="share-toggle as-1">[ CLICK HERE ]</div>

<div class="audio-share as1">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>

<div class="share-toggle as-2">[ CLICK HERE ]</div>

<div class="audio-share as2">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

I hope you will consider this answer.
And I hope it will help!